# unable to do a successful POST to my php using jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html, post

What I am trying to do is , send my form fields i.e username and password(encrypted) values to a php file and simply echo them (password after decrypting). However, if i view my Network tab in developer tools, it does send a post from my html file but if i try to see console values, my ajax itself is not runnin the success function and if i try to see my php file it also just doesnt recognize my post.

here is my html:

```
 <form id="userDetailsForm">
<div class="clear"></div> <div class="clear"></div>
<p>Add User</p>
<div class="clear"></div>
<label for="usr">Username</label>
<input type="text" name="usr" id="usr">
<label for="pwd">Password</label>
<input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd">
<button id="create" class="create" type="button" name="createButton">Create</button>
```

Following is the jquery ajax code: -

```
$("#create").click(function(){

    var passwordForNewUser=CryptoJS.AES.encrypt($("#pwd").val(),key).toString();
    var decryptedPassword=CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(passwordForNewUser,key).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
    console.log("decrypted password: "+decryptedPassword);
    console.log("create clicked");
    formdata = {
        usr: $("#usr").val(),
        pwd: passwordForNewUser,
    };

    var userNamePresentInTable=$("#usr").val();
    var password=CryptoJS.AES.encrypt($("#pwd").val(),key).toString();
    if($("td:contains('" + formdata.usr + "')").text() === formdata.usr){
        $("#userErrorDiv").html("User already exists. Please enter another one").css("color","red");
        duplicateUser=true;
    }else{
        duplicateUser=false;

        /*before adding to table save it in localStorage*/
       /* myLocalStorage.setItem(formdata.usr,formdata.pwd);*/

        $("#userErrorDiv").html("");
        var tr=$('<tr></tr>');
        var enteredVal=$("#usr").val();

        var td_username=$('<td></td>',{
            text:  $("#usr").val()
        }).addClass("editableFields").appendTo(tr);

        var td_level=$('<td></td>', {
            text: "User"
        }).appendTo(tr);

        var td_buttons=$('<td></td>',{
            html: '<button class="edit">Edit</button> <button class="del">Delete</button> <button class="apply">Apply</button>'
        }).appendTo(tr);

        $(tr).find("button").button();
        $(".userTable").append(tr);

        $("#userDetailsForm").submit();
    }
});

 $("#userDetailsForm").submit(function(e){

    var passwordForNewUser=CryptoJS.AES.encrypt($("#pwd").val(),key).toString();

  console.log(formdata);

    if(duplicateUser || userNotPresent){
        //do nothing...no ajax
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    else{

    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url: '/scripts/username&passw.php',
        data: { usr: $("#usr").val(),
                pwd: passwordForNewUser
              },
        success:function(data){
            console.log("Data sent: "+data);
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log("Error encountered while sending");
        }
    });
        e.preventDefault();

    }


});
```

And following is my php code:-

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json", true);

if(isset($_POST['usr'])){
    $username=$_POST['usr'];
    $password=$_POST['pwd'];
    $key="encyrptedPassword";
    $decrypted_password=mcrypt_decrypt("AES",$key,$password);
     echo "Encrypted password recieved: ".$key;
    echo "Decypted password recieved: ".$decrypted_password;
}
else    {
            echo "problem recieving form data";
}

?>
```

Comment: `<form id="userDetailsForm">` If you don't specify a `method` it defaults to `GET`. `<form id="userDetailsForm" method='post'>`

Comment: Also I wouldn't use an ampersand in filenames - they are reserved to separate GET request parameters: `url: '/scripts/username&passw.php',`

Comment: But if im specifying POST in my $.ajax shouldnt it take that one? I have seen this link where he doesnt use anything in form because he is using post in ajax https://www.airpair.com/js/jquery-ajax-post-tutorial

Comment: Why do you have `header("Content-Type: application/json", true);` if you're outputting plain text? This will cause jQuery to throw an error because `Encrypted password recieved: ` isn't valid json.. (recieved should be received)

Comment: Do you get any console output? If the success function doesn't print anything, the error function should.

Comment: I already removed that json thing. Sorry about that. However, when i tried echoing <pre> that you suggested, in developer console i do get an array showing my username and encrypted password I pass . However when i go to php file , I only see a blank array been rendered.

Comment: And yes ever since i added that part which u suggested , my success function now prints data sent on console. However, my php side is still blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your php side is not working because your ajax code is sending a JSON data via POST.  On your php code, you need to use file_get_contents("php://input") to extract the username and password.  Just add something like this in your php file:

```
$incomingData = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

json_decode will convert your JSON object into a php array.  You should then be able to access the values via

```
$incomingData["usr"] and $incomingData["pwd"]
```

if you like.